# Maple is left ''evaluating'' when using the solve command on the following equation

Tags: math, system, equation-solving, maple

I have used the code in the image, when compiling the entire sheet, it stays in "evaluating" for several hours. Is there a way to speed up the process or fix this problem?

Maple code: https://www.mediafire.com/file/gcgmmkm27zd5gw3/Sistemadeec.mw/file

[image: 1]

I want to solve the system of equations with 5 variables, by giving R6 a value I would have 4 equations and 4 variables. What I expect maple to return is alpha angles 2,3,4,5.

Answer (score 1):

Those floating-point shifts and scalings of the trig frequencies make it less appropriate to use an exact, symbolic approach such as the `solve` command.

The command `fsolve` quickly gets this solution,

```
fsolve({Ec1, Ec2, Ec3, Ec4},
       {alpha2, alpha3, alpha4, alpha5});

     {alpha2 = 21.80736535, alpha3 = 12.92753812,
      alpha4 = 49.12870654, alpha5 = 87.28474753}
```

Also, there seems to be no reason for using the fixed precision floating-point approximation `evalf[20](Pi)` for this example, instead of simply `Pi`.

The solution using `fsolve` appears to behave well if the working precision is increased by raising the value of `Digits`.

By the way, you uploaded worksheet indicates that it was last saved in Maple version 18.02 (2014). It's usually a good idea to mention if you're using a version that is nine major releases out of date.

Comment: So, what more would you want, so that you might *accept* an Answer?